# Android MotionLayout state not updating when changing constraint programatically

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I have a very simple MotionLayout and I'm trying to change the visibility of one of the constraints programatically and have the view reflect that change. However the change isn't reflected until I transition away from the current state and then come back to it. How do you get the view to update itself based on the new constraint immediately? I've tried `updateState()`, `rebuildScene()` and `invalidate()` but none of them seem to do anything.

Here is the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_scene"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left_to_right_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Left to right"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top_to_bottom_text"
            android:text="Top to bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Here is the MotionScene:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <Transition
            app:constraintSetStart="@id/base"
            app:constraintSetEnd="@id/bottom">
        <OnClick
                app:targetId="@id/top_to_bottom_text">

        </OnClick>

    </Transition>

    <Transition
            app:constraintSetStart="@id/base"
            app:constraintSetEnd="@id/right">
        <OnSwipe
                app:dragDirection="dragRight"
                app:touchAnchorId="@id/left_to_right_text"
                app:touchAnchorSide="right">

        </OnSwipe>

    </Transition>


    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/base">

        <Constraint
                android:id="@id/left_to_right_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Constraint
                android:id="@id/top_to_bottom_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/bottom">

        <Constraint
                android:id="@id/left_to_right_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Constraint
                android:id="@id/top_to_bottom_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/right">

        <Constraint
                android:id="@id/left_to_right_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Constraint
                android:id="@id/top_to_bottom_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

And here's the code where I'm attempting to update the visibility one of the text views after 2 seconds:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        Completable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                motion_layout.getConstraintSet(R.id.base)?.let {
                    it.setVisibility(R.id.left_to_right_text, View.INVISIBLE)
                }
                motion_layout.updateState()
                // These don't work either
//                motion_layout.rebuildScene()
//                motion_layout.invalidate()
            }
    }
```

You can see in the gif below, I wait 2 seconds and nothing happens. It's not until I transition to a new state and then come back to the original one that the visibility is updated.
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**I found a solution!**

*The solution provided by Phan Van Linh does not work for me (I am using 2.0.0-beta1 constraint version)*

Just call .requestLayout() on view you just changed visibility(or other view properties)
So in your example:

```
motion_layout.getConstraintSet(R.id.base)?.let {
                it.setVisibility(R.id.left_to_right_text, View.INVISIBLE)
                yourView.requestLayout() // <-- this line
            }
```

Due to documentation for requestLayout method it will go through all view`s hierarchy currently in a layout pass.

Comment: Oh cool, ya that seems to work! Although your code is a bit wrong, you're calling requestLayout on the constraint set not the view. Should be (using synthetic accessors) left_to_right_text.requestLayout() not it.requestLayout(). Would really like to know what updateState, rebuildSchene and invalidate are supposed to. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm using `2.0.0-beta1` too, I checked again I see my workaround it still working, not sure why?. However, anyway your solution is better solution. Thank you for find this cool function, I never know it can do more thing then invalidate

Answer (score 0):

try:
updateState(R.id.base, ConstraintSet  )

Comment: Is this what you meant? If so it doesn't work either Completable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                val set = motion_layout.getConstraintSet(R.id.base)?.apply {
                    this.setVisibility(R.id.left_to_right_text, View.INVISIBLE)
                }
                motion_layout.updateState(R.id.base, set)
            }

Comment: This works for me, but is a bit of a hack, LionisIAm's answer is better I think. Thanks for trying though!